# Sum of subcategory in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with category and subcategory field. I want the summation of different subcategory under a particular category. Like Table

```
Category  | Sub category | Amount 
----------+--------------+--------
Children  |  Cloth       |  200
Children  |  Cloth       |  500
Transport |  Fuel        |  300
Children  |  School      |  500
```

I want the sum of cloth  under children category. Like that for different category. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your question exactly what you want, but I think it's one of the following:

It you want *every* sub category of *every* category, do this:

```
select
    category,
    sub_category,
    sum(amount) as total
from mytable
group by category, sub_category
```

If you want *just* the sub categories of "Children", do this:

```
select
    sub_category,
    sum(amount) as total
from mytable
group by sub_category
where category = 'Children'
```

Comment: I want sum of each sub category under a particular category like sum of amt for clothing under children and sum of the amt for school under children. Follow the table you can under stand. Thanks for reply

Comment: The second query is the one you want then.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
SELECT
     sub_category
    ,sum(amount)
FROM
    the_table
GROUP BY
    sub_category
WHERE
    category = 'Children';
```

or

```
SELECT
     category
    ,sub_category
    ,sum(amount)
FROM
    the_table
GROUP BY
     category
    ,sub_category
```

---

Tested/demoed using SQLite:

```
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.15.2 2013-01-09 11:53:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t ( category varchar, subcategory varchar, amount int);
sqlite> insert into t values ('children', 'cloth', 200), ('children', 'cloth', 500), ('transport', 'fuel', 300), ('children', 'school', 500);
sqlite> select * from t ;
children|cloth|200
children|cloth|500
transport|fuel|300
children|school|500
sqlite> 
sqlite> select category, subcategory, sum(amount) from t group by category, subcategory;
children|cloth|700
children|school|500
transport|fuel|300
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    category,
    sub_category,
    sum(amount) as total
from mytable where sub_category = 'Cloth'
group by category, sub_category
```

Comment: "Like that for different category." he meant it as as an example. +1 vote anyway :-)